# .net core middleware automatically sets the content type to application/json; charset=utf-8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have created a middleware in my asp.net core (3.0 SDK) web API application. I am facing a strange issue in middleware. When _next.Invoke(context) completes its execution, it sets the content type to **application/json; charset=utf-8** though there is none specified in headers.

Below is the code for middleware:

```
 public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            using (var newBodyStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                try
                {
                    context.Response.Body = newBodyStream;
                    var contentTypeBefore = context.Response.ContentType; //Returns null

                    await _next.Invoke(context);

                   var contentTypeAfter = context.Response.ContentType; //Returns application/json; charset=utf-8

                    context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;

                    if (context.Response.StatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        await HandleNotSuccessRequestAsync(context, context.Response.StatusCode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string bodyAsText = await FormatResponse(newBodyStream);
                        await HandleSuccessRequestAsync(context, bodyAsText, context.Response.StatusCode);
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
                    newBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    await newBodyStream.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
                }


            }
        }
```

Whereas I am returning StatusCode from my controller like below:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            ApiResponseModel<IEnumerable<CompanyMasterDto>> apiResponseModel;
            apiResponseModel = await _repository.CompanyMasterRepository.GetAllCompaniesAsync();
            return StatusCode(apiResponseModel.ErrorCode, apiResponseModel);
        }
```

Note: It won't make any difference if I try to retrieve **contentTypeAfter** value after execution of below statement

```
 context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
```

Is there anything wrong with the above code or its something else as the change in content type will be a hurdle when handling content negotiation or something else in the middlewares.

Hereby posting some of the messages from the output window which I think could be helpful to find out the issue:

**Attempting to select an output formatter based on Accept header '*/*' and explicitly specified content types 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.**

**No output formatter was found for content types 'application/json; charset=utf-8, application/json; charset=utf-8' to write the response.**

Answer (score 4):

I think your code is fine.

By default, asp.net core always returns of type `application/json; charset=utf-8`. You can return other formats, for example XML if you add the code

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

and add an `Accept` header with the value `application/xml`

This microsoft docs can explain it better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I already had that in my code. as  `                             
    services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                //To accept browser headers.
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            }).
            AddXmlSerializerFormatters().
            AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters(). `  Is there any option to set that to application/json instead of application/json; charset=utf-8 by default if no headers are specified?